# Passing choice parameter via url for building a parameterized job remotely

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to build a parameterized Jenkins job remotely by passing the parameters through a url.

I tried doing a curl request with POST.

```
 http://user:passwd@jenkins_url/job/TestParameterizedBuild/buildWithParameters?string_param=abc123&bool_param=true&choice_param=Green&token=TOKEN_VAL
```

The string and boolean parameters get the correct values - `abc123` and `true` respectively. But the choice parameter takes the value `Red` instead of `Green`.
[The choices provided for `choice_param` field are - `Red, Green, Blue`, in that order]. I guess it is always taking the default.
Am i passing the value to choice parameter `choice_param` wrongly?

Comment: Did you find a solution for that ?

Comment: No. Nothing suggested below worked for me.

Comment: I found a workaround, it works for me, try that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56678546/passing-choice-parameter-via-url-for-building-a-parameterized-job-remotely/64133727#64133727

Answer (score 0):

Try to use curl and rebuild your current build command:

http://user:passwd@jenkins_url/job/TestParameterizedBuild/buildWithParameters?string_param=abc123&bool_param=true&choice_param=Green&token=TOKEN_VAL

into curl build command:

curl -X POST -u Login:Pass "http://jenkins_url/job/TestParameterizedBuild/buildWithParameters?string_param=abc123&bool_param=true&choice_param=Green&token=TOKEN_VAL"

**Remember to put link into quotes ""!**
Without quotes you pass only first parameter and rest of parameters will have default values.

Answer (score 0):

I found workaround - in case you are able to modify the Jenkins Job

All you need to do is to replace your "Choice Parameter" to type of "Extended Choice Parameter", definition for example:

[image]

By this definition, it will looks as Drop Down List, same like "Choice Parameter",
but it should work the same like "String Parameter"
For above parameter I used URL link to trigger a build:

http://illin123:8070/job/VAPP_BOUNCE/buildWithParameters?ACTION=ping

Answer (score -1):

Try passing field (e.g. 1, 2, 3...) instead of passing choice parameter's actual value. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Did you mean - `http://user:passwd@jenkins_url/job/TestParameterizedBuild/buildWithParameters?string_param=abc123&bool_param=true&choice_param=2&token=TOKEN_VAL`? When i try to do this it takes the value of `choice_param` as `2` and not `Green`.

Comment: Ok. Then try ```2.Green```. I haven't myself tried passing choice parameters. If this solution also dosen't work then let me know. I will try it out and let you know.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This didn't work either. It is displaying the default option `Red` always.